# Odd behavior concerning Django's admin page saving files

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, static, mod-wsgi

I have Django 4.1.7 website, served by apache2 on Ubuntu PC.

in the .conf file of apache2: `Alias /static /mnt/hdd/SIMSY/static/` and Django works as expected.
All CSS, JS, Images are loaded just fine.

But when adding new object using Django's built-in admin site, the site tries saving the images on `/static` in the root of Ubuntu (it caused Permission error, then I tried creating that folder in the root and it actually saved the image in that folder).

How is Django trying to save in `/static` while apache2 tells it that `/static` is `/mnt/hdd/SIMSY/static`?

I assume there is something can be changed in settings.py to solve that, what can be changed?

Here is the part of settings.py that has anything to do with static:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading files are not static files. These are media files.
You need to set [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#media-root) and [MEDIA_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#media-url) in your settings file to handle them properly.

Here are some more useful links on how to handle user uploaded files in django:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/files/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/#serving-uploaded-files-in-development to serve them during development